# Python Is there an endless/circular loop import in my case?

Tags: python, python-import

I was developing a module, but it occurred an import error which made me confused:

```
 File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/tests/test_in_ipython.py", line 3, in <module>
    from KE import KE
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from KE.client import KE, KE3, KE4
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    from KE.v4.client import KE4
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/v4/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from KE.v4.client import KE4
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/v4/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from KE.v4.model import Model
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/v4/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from KE.v4.client import KE4  # TODO how to import here?
ImportError: cannot import name 'KE4' from 'KE.v4.client' (/PycharmProjects/KE-py/KE/v4/client.py)
```

The tree is like this:

```
├── KE
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── v3
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── client.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   └── v4
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── client.py
│       ├── model.py
```

KE/client.py

```
from KE.v3.client import KE3
from KE.v4.client import KE4
```

`KE/__init__.py`

```
from KE.client import KE, KE3, KE4
```

`KE/v4/__init__.py`

```
from KE.v4.client import KE4
```

KE/v4/model.py

```
from KE.v4.client import KE4  # TODO how to import here? 
# When I comment this line, everything will work find.
```

I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know whats going on, but the line ```from KE.v4.client import KE4``` is in model.py and in client.py is that right

Comment: `KE.v4.client` imports `Model`, and `Model` imports `KE.v4.client`. Yes, you have a circular import. Why do both modules need to require each other at all? That's questionable circular logic.

Comment: Ohhh, it's a circular import, do you have any recommendation to avoid the error?  because it does make sense to import in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
in `model.py`

```
import KE.v4.client as client_v4
KE4 = client_v4.KE4
```

in order to work around this, use import, rather than from import